# jQuery unexpected behaviour on page load?

Tags: jquery

i receive some jquery errors not every page load but sometime it gives me the error in the browser console but when i refresh the page that error will not remains any more. and then again different error produced while loading the page?
Erors are something like

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function
jQuery('#spic-catlogues').owlCarousel({
```

maybe this is due to some of my scripts are loading before their respective libraries are loading or any other issue ?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded before `owlCarousel`? Is `.ready()` used? Is `'#spic-catlogues'` a dynamically created element? Can you create a stacksnippets to reproduce issue?

Comment: Please share library Reference and `.ready()` code.

Comment: this is not the error that i got every time.

Comment: I got different error on each page load . but this is not accured every page load